# Stopping the box from moving

Tags: javafx

I have a rectangular box as my object and a button. I have created a scene thereafter and added the box and button into the canvas.

After clicking the button for the first time the box starts moving, and after clicking the button for the 2nd time it should stop moving, but it continues.

```java
    import javafx.animation.Animation;
    import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
    import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
    import javafx.animation.Timeline;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.util.Duration;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import java.awt.*;

    import static java.awt.Color.RED;

    public class Main extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    Button btn = new Button();
    Pane canvas = new Pane();
    Rectangle box = new Rectangle(5, 10, 20, 30);
    int a=0;

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception 
    {

        Scene scene = new Scene(canvas, 800, 600);
        box.setFill(Color.rgb(255,0,0));
        box.relocate(100, 550);
        canvas.getChildren().addAll(box, btn);

        stage.setTitle("Moving Ball");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        btn.setOnAction(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void handle (ActionEvent event)
    {
        Bounds bounds = canvas.getBoundsInLocal();
        Timeline timeline=new Timeline();

        if(a==1) 
        {
            a=0;

            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10),
                    new KeyValue(box.layoutXProperty() , box.getX())))

            timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
            timeline.play();

        }
        else
        {
            a=1;

            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10),
                   new KeyValue(box.layoutXProperty(), bounds.getMaxY() - box.getWidth())));

            timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
            timeline.play();

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

The box should stop on even-numbered clicks and start moving on odd-numbered clicks.

Comment: I don't see any code where you're attempting to stop it... What have you tried so far?

Comment: unrelated: don't mix awt stuff into fx applications

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it looks like you just started coding not necessarily a bad thing but there are some things you should do as good coding practice

Such as `if(a==1) {`t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶b̶o̶o̶l̶e̶a̶n̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶s̶ ̶w̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶u̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶d̶o̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶n̶e̶e̶d̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶s̶t̶o̶r̶e̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶o̶b̶j̶e̶c̶t̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶m̶o̶v̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶ ̶b̶o̶o̶l̶e̶a̶n̶ ̶w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶j̶u̶s̶t̶ ̶f̶i̶n̶e̶ As @Sedrick said in the comment below "you could have used getStatus()" which makes more sense because then you don't have to flip the boolean or modify an int each time

> public final Animation.Status getStatus() Gets the value of the property status. Property description: The status of the Animation. In Animation can be in one of three states: Animation.Status.STOPPED, Animation.Status.PAUSED or Animation.Status.RUNNING

Next read more into event handlers you don't need to `implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>`  to handle an action you can do something like so `btn.setOnAction(event -> handle(event));`

After that you don't need to create a new timeline every time you click the button just initialize it once and leave it at that

Moving on to `Timeline`s to stop a `Timeline` you simply do `timeline.stop();`

So when you put it all together it look something like this:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private Button btn = new Button();
    private Pane canvas = new Pane();
    private Rectangle box = new Rectangle(5, 10, 20, 30);
    private Timeline timeline=new Timeline();
    //int a=0;
    private boolean isMoving = false;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        box.setFill(Color.rgb(255,0,0));
        box.relocate(100, 550);
        canvas.getChildren().addAll(box, btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(canvas, 800, 600);


        stage.setTitle("Moving Ball");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        Bounds bounds = canvas.getBoundsInLocal();
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10),
                        new KeyValue(box.layoutXProperty(), bounds.getMaxX() - box.getWidth())));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

        btn.setOnAction(event -> handle());
    }

    private void handle() {
        if(timeline.getStatus()== Animation.Status.RUNNING) {
            //a=0;
            //timeline.getKeyFrames().add(
            //        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10), new KeyValue(box.layoutXProperty() , box.getX()))
            //);
            //timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
            //timeline.play();
            //isMoving = false;
            timeline.stop();

        }
        else {
            //a=1;
            //isMoving = true;
            timeline.play();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a boolean control, you could have used `getStatus()`. I think it makes more sense. `public final Animation.Status getStatus()
Gets the value of the property status.
Property description:
The status of the Animation. In Animation can be in one of three states: Animation.Status.STOPPED, Animation.Status.PAUSED or Animation.Status.RUNNING.`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend adding more and more `KeyFrame`s to the same `Timeline`; replace the old ones. Furthermore since `Animation.Status` is an enum, using `equals` is not necessary; `==` works too.